# LDAP group not showing in Gerrit

Tags: ldap, gerrit

I am using Gerrit with LDAP auth. My gerrit config is like:

```
server = ldap://192.168.1.100:389
username = cn=admin,dc=doman,dc=com,dc=cn
groupsVisibleToAll = true
accountBase = ou=Users,dc=domain,dc=com,dc=cn
accountScope = subtree
accountPattern = (&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(uid=${username}))
accountFullName = sn
accountEmailAddress = mail
accountSshUserName = uid
#accountMemberField = memberOf
#accountMemberExpandGroups = true
#fetchMemberOfEagerly = true
groupBase = ou=Groups,dc=domain,dc=com,dc=cn
groupScope = subtree
groupPattern = (&(objectClass=groupOfUniqueNames)(cn=${groupname}))
groupMemberPattern = (&(objectClass=groupOfUniqueNames)(uniqueMember=${dn}))
groupName = cn
```

LDAP tree is like:

```
+--> dc=domain,dc=com,dc=cn (3)
  ---> cn=admin
  +--> ou=Groups (2)
  | ---> cn=admin
  | ---> cn=dev
  +--> ou=Users (3)
  | ---> cn=gerrit
  | ---> cn=jenkins
  | ---> cn=test
```

I add `memberOf` relative to LDAP myself, the group object class is `groupOfUniqueNames`, the user object class is inetOrgPerson.
`groupOfUniqueNames` contains a attribute ``````uniqueMember which contains the `dn` of group users. `inetOrgPerson` contains a attribute `memberOf` is the dn of it's group.

But I can't login when I add `accountMemberField`. And the LDAP groups is not showing in gerrit.

Doc: https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-gerrit.html#ldap

Comment: Hey did you ever find the answer to this?

Comment: Just type ldap/dev to define ldap dev group in gerrit.

Comment: thanks that works!

Answer (score 1):

If you can login gerrit with the LDAP account. Just go to Gerrit project access add a LDAP group use `ldap/*`. * is the LDAP group name.